# display default values in node form

Tags: nodes, forms

Can  you help me please with node form in the Drupal 7?

I have a three forms (node/add/A, node/add/B, node/add/C). 
Values in the node/add/A are created after registration.

How to display a values with node/add/A to the node/add/B like default values a field?

Sorry for my English. 
Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: well you explained your problem not so good, but as far as I get what you mean maybe you can try entity reference?

Comment: I am sorry ... I have a form node/add/A and in the node form a field with machine name field_blog_author. I need use value with field_blog_autor in other form (example node/add/B) like default value for field field_blog_name. I hope you understand me.

Comment: you still not explaining the problem properly, anyway seems like I can't help but search google for "Drupal Entity refrence" it might help you a bit :)

Comment: I am sorry ... I have a form node/add/A and in the node form a field with machine name field_blog_author. I need use value with field_blog_autor in other form (example node/add/B) like default value for field field_blog_name. I hope you understand me.   
 OK I try it "Drupal Entity reference". I am sorry and thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

well based on your comment:

Use the [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You
>   can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the
>   database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the
>   fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use
>   requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss
>   Army knife of CCK fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!